# Continuity of a retraction

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading the paper *A Condition for the Absolute Homotopy Extension Property* by G. S. Young and trying to understand why this retraction he defines is continuous.

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$ be a closed subspace. Suppose that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $A$ that is deformable into $A$ rel $A$. Explicitly, this means there is a homotopy $H \colon U \times I \rightarrow X$ such that $H(x,0) = x$, $H(a,t) = a$, and $H(x,1) \in A$ for all $x \in U$, $a \in A$, and $t \in I$. Moreover, suppose there is a function $\varphi \colon X \rightarrow I$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(1) = A$ and $\varphi(x) = 0$ if $x \notin U$.

Young then defines the retraction
$$
 r \colon X \times I \rightarrow (A \times I) \cup (X \times 0), \ (x,t) \mapsto \begin{cases}
        (x,0) & \text{if} \ \varphi(x) = 0 \\
        (H(x,2\varphi(x)t),0) & \text{if} \ 0 < \varphi(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \\
        (H(x,\frac{t}{2(1 - \varphi(x))}),0) & \text{if} \ \frac{1}{2} \leqslant \varphi(x) < 1 \\
            & \ \text{and} \ t \leqslant 2(1 - \varphi(x)) \\
        (H(x,1), t - 2(1 - \varphi(x))) & \text{if} \ \frac{1}{2} \leqslant \varphi(x) < 1 \\
            & \ \text{and} \ 2(1 - \varphi(x)) \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \\
        (x,t) & \text{if} \ \varphi(x) = 1,
    \end{cases}
$$
and notes that it is trivially continuous, except as $\varphi(x)$ approaches $1$. I was actually able to show that continuity at points with $\varphi(x) = 1$, but it is the $\varphi(x) = 0$ points that are bothering me, since these points are not in $U$, where $H$ is defined.

I'm completely stumped on how to do this. I tried using a net $(x_i,t_i)$ converging to $(x,t)$ with $\varphi(x) = 0$, but I really did not get anywhere with this. I was also not able to prove that the preimage of an open interval is open, and also made little to no progress.

I should say that although Young takes $X$ to be normal and $A$ to be a $G_\delta$ set, the claim should hold without these assumptions; for example Arne Strom uses the same retraction in his paper *Note on Cofibrations*, without the added assumptions. There he claims that continuity is straightforward to check and omits the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I think I've found a solution. I think the point is that we can assume that $\varphi$ is zero on an open neighbourhood of $\partial U$, the topological boundary of the subspace $U \subseteq X$. If this is not the case, we can replace $\varphi$ with the function
$$
\varphi'(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if} \ 0 \leqslant \varphi(x) \leqslant \frac12 \\
    2\varphi(x) - 1 & \text{if} \ \frac12 \leqslant \varphi(x) \leqslant 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\varphi'$ retains the properties of $\varphi$, and is zero on $\partial U$.

It is now clear that $r$ is continuous at points with $\varphi(x) = 0$.